# Removing a specific div container within another div

Tags: python, web-scraping

As titled in the mention, I was doing web-scraping and I do not know how to exclude a div within another div in the main_paragraphs function:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def scrape_minimalism():
    base_url = "https://www.theminimalists.com/minimalism/"
    
    response = requests.get(base_url)
    
    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        
        title = soup.find('h1', class_='entry-title').text.strip()
        print('\n', title)
        
        main_paragraphs = soup.find('div', class_='entry-content').find_all('p', class_=lambda x: x != 'ymae')

        main_pcontent = '\n'.join(paragraph.text.strip() for paragraph in main_paragraphs)
        print('\n', main_pcontent)
            
        
scrape_minimalism()
```

my goal here is to exclude `class = 'ymae'` under another bigger `div` container `class = 'entry-content'`

the problem here is that the paragraphs of the web under `class 'entry-content'` are unsorted and that it is difficult to extract data from since it has no other container. So that's why it also includes another sub `div 'ymae'`

I tried doing `extract()` or `x.get` and `x.split`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can first select all tags you want to delete and `.extract()` them and then get text from the `<p>` tags that left:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def scrape_minimalism():
    base_url = "https://www.theminimalists.com/minimalism/"

    response = requests.get(base_url)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

        title = soup.find("h1", class_="entry-title").get_text(strip=True)
        print("\n", title)

        # delete tags you don't want first:

        for to_delete in soup.select(".ymae, .subscribe-line"):
            to_delete.extract()

        main_paragraphs = soup.select(".entry-content p")

        main_pcontent = "\n".join(
            paragraph.get_text(strip=True) for paragraph in main_paragraphs
        )
        print("\n", main_pcontent)


scrape_minimalism()
```

Prints:

```
 What Is Minimalism?

 So what is thisminimalismthing? It’s quite simple: to be a minimalist you must live with less than 100 things, you can’t own a car or a home or a television, you can’t have a career, you must live in exotic hard-to-pronounce places all over the world, you must start a blog, you can’t have children, and you must bea young white male from a privileged background.

...
```